# jQuery show/hide methods arent working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here is my codepen for you guys to play with.... [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/cmseaton42/pen/wJaoYx)

I cannot seem to get the `#play-again` button to show up once a game has finished using `$('#play-again').show()`.

Any thoughts on this???

**Update** Added raw html link

Comment: You don't have a button on the page with id `play-again`

Comment: Put normal HTML code. Not PUG Preprocessod

Comment: @MichaelCoker the OP put it there but it is pre-processed code.

Comment: @SagarV  you are correct.

Comment: The updated link should be raw html.... sorry about that.

Comment: @SagarV ah, I finished the game and their code is removing the button from the DOM when finished. I searched the DOM for it after I finished, and it's removed.

Comment: The intent is to hide the button on the DOM loading and show it once the game has finished...  I am not sure why it is not working correctly though i am sure I just dont understant something about how these methods work.

Comment: instead of `replay.show();replay.addClass('load-in');` use `$('#play-again').show();$('#play-again').addClass('load-in');`

Comment: @canaanseaton the button is in `.banner p` and you're replacing all of the contents of `.banner p` when someone finishes the game, which removes the button from the page.

Comment: not preserving html on text method

Comment: just move the button outside of the p, since you're replacing everything in the p with "you lose!" or "you win!" when someone finishes http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/mWJOap

Comment: instead of `replay.show();replay.addClass('load-in');` use `$('#play-again').show();$('#play-again').addClass('load-in');`

Comment: @MichaelCoker that makes sense.... I will fix this issue... thanks for the help!

Comment: @canaanseaton no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner">
    <p>tic-tac-toe</p>
      <button id="play-again"> <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></button>
    
  </div>
  <div class="board">
    <div class="row" id="row-1">
      <div class="col" id="col-1-1">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="col-1-2">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="col-1-3">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="row-2">
      <div class="col" id="col-2-1">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="col-2-2">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="col-2-3">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="row-3">
      <div class="col" id="col-3-1">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="col-3-2">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="col-3-3">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that you must place the `button#play-again` outside the `p` when i changed, it is working for me